# A class member function calling a class friend function (all same class) Possible?

Tags: c++, class, member, friend-function

I have a pretty basic class with member functions and private data, but I want the print function not to be a part of the class member functions.  I remove it from the class and declare it as a friend and it works when called directly from main.cpp, but when a class member function calls it internally it is not declared.  I know being a friend gives it access to data, but how do I make it available to the member functions?  Is it possible?

```
//HEADER FILE
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static const int ArrSize=3;

class TicTacToe
  {
    //friends
    friend void printBoard(char [][ArrSize]);

    //member functions
    public:
    void makeboard();
    void isValidMove();
    void isWinner();
    void getMove();

    //data members
    private:
    int pRow, pCol, player;
    bool validMove, winner;
    char TTTarray[ArrSize][ArrSize];
};

void TicTacToe::getMove()
{
  //  some internal code for determining if proper input
  // calls printBoard() to show what move was made.
  printBoard(0);

void printBoard(char TTTarray[][ArrSize])
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      cout << TTTarray[i][0] << " " << TTTarray[i][0] << " " << TTTarray[i][2] << endl;
    }
  }

  // MAIN.CPP FILE
  #include <iostream>
  #include "TicTacToe.h"

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    TicTacToe a;
    a.makeBoard();
    printBoard(0);
    a.getMove();

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Definitely need to see some code here.

Comment: It's not declared. Have you forgot to include header file with print declaration?

Comment: Dmitri - Thanks for the response.  Not sure if I know what you mean though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where you use `printBoard` inside `getMove`, `printBoard` indeed hasn't been declared. You need to either move the definition of `printBoard` before `getMove` (with the definition available, it is also declared) or add at least a declaration

```
void printBoard(char [][ArrSize]);
```

outside the class (also before you use it anywhere). In addition, your code does not compile because there is at least one typo (upper case, lower case makeBoard), the definition of makeBoard is missing and the closing brace of getMove is missing. Also, maybe you want to call printBoard with TTTarray instead of 0?

PS: Please post code with proper indentation next time. It is really hard to check whether parentheses balance like this...